# On click play a section of a mp3

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have many buttons playing many different sounds - each button plays a different mp3 when clicked.  Example code:

```
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio src="1.mp3"  ></audio>1</a>
```

For mobile devices I am trying to play all the different sounds from the same mp3 file, so I can preload 1 file and have more instant experience.

So I would need to set the starting point and end point of the mp3 to be played when clicked.

How do I do that using audio html5 or javascript?  Working in just chrome is enough...

Answer (score 1):

If i got your question right, you want to play different time stamp of a audio file simultaneously or whenever you want

here is one example which you can use

```html
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t=00:00:00" 
       >
</audio>Part 1
</a>
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t=00:00:56" >
</audio>Part 2
</a>
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t=00:01:00" >
</audio>Part 3
</a>
```

you can also give time in seconds instead of timestamp like

```html
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t=0" 
       >
</audio>Part 1
</a>
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t=56" >
</audio>Part 2
</a>
<a onclick="this.firstChild.play()"><audio id="audio2" 
       preload="auto" 
       src="http://cld3097web.audiovideoweb.com/va90web25003/companions/Foundations%20of%20Rock/5.01.mp3#t60" >
</audio>Part 3
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, but this should work:

```
<a id="audioTag1"><audio src="1.mp3"  ></audio>1</a>
```

```
var canPlay = false;
var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('audio')[0];

document.getElementById('audioTag1').addEventListener('click', function(){
    playAudio(15);
});

audio.addEventListener('canplay', function() { // listen for the `canplay`event, to make sure the file is loaded.
    canPlay = true; // Set a boolean to "true" once the audio has loaded.
});

function playAudio(time){
    audio.currentTime = time; // jump to 15 secs into the file
    audio.play(); // I'm not certain if this line is necessary.
}
```

Make sure you run the JS code in a `onload` event listener, so the audio tag is loaded when the code is executed.

Comment: Im not sure I get your last comment.  Im running off harddrive so there should not be delay of loading.  But running the script clean I get error - audio is undefined - audio.currentTime = time;   If I put the code in if (document.readyState === "complete") { init(); var...} I get playAudio is not defined-  playAudio(15).  Not sure how or what.  Thanks

Comment: @Jon: I made a small modification to the code, try running this in your `readyState` piece of code.

Comment: I had to change to getElementById (w/o s) - with the ready listener no errors and no sound.  W/o the listener TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null   As I am using desktop there I shouldnt need to wait to load?

Comment: You need to test for the `canPlay` variable--right now, you declare and set, but do not read, it.